# How to pass state between screens in React Native

Tags: react-native

This is screen 1, where I am supposed to be passing the state for button text.

```
export class EditProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.navigateToName = this.navigateToName.bind(this);
    this.navigateToAboutMe = this.navigateToAboutMe.bind(this);
    this.navigateToInterests = this.navigateToInterests.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      showing: true,
      aboutUser: {
        buttonText: "hey",
        showing: false,
      },
    };
  }
  navigateToName = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("CreateProfile", {
      showing: false,
    });
  };
  navigateToAboutMe = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("AboutUser", {
      aboutUser: this.state.aboutUser,
    });
  };
  navigateToInterests = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Interests", { showing: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={ProfileEditStyle.justifyImage}>
          <Image
            style={ProfileEditStyle.image}
            source={require("../../Graphics/jessica_alba.jpg")}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text style={ProfileEditStyle.basictext}>Basic Info</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={ProfileEditStyle.buttons}>
            <Text style={ProfileEditStyle.text} onPress={this.navigateToName}>
              Edit Name
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={ProfileEditStyle.buttons}>
            <Text style={ProfileEditStyle.text}>Edit Photo</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={ProfileEditStyle.buttons}>
            <Text style={ProfileEditStyle.text}>Edit Location</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={ProfileEditStyle.buttons}
            onPress={this.navigateToAboutMe}
          >
            <Text style={ProfileEditStyle.text}>Edit About Me</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={ProfileEditStyle.buttons}
            onPress={this.navigateToInterests}
          >
            <Text style={ProfileEditStyle.text}>Edit Interests</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default EditProfile;
```

This is screen 2, where I want the state for the buttonText to change on the continue button component.

```
export class AboutUser extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.navigatToInterests = this.navigatToInterests.bind(this);
            this.checkEntry = this.checkEntry.bind(this);
            var params = props.navigation.state.params.aboutUser;
        
            this.state = {
              value: "",
            };
      }

  

    <ContinueButton
                  text={this.props.route.params.aboutUser.buttonText}
                  color="#ff304f"
                  style={CreateAboutMe.centerButton}
                  onPress={this.navigatToInterests}
                />
```

I am trying to do conditional rendering for the continue button component. When its on one screen I want it to say "continue" and when its on another route I want it to say " Save and Go Back". However when I try to change the state between screens for some reason I either get a params error or the state doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Get parameter from previous screen :

```
constructor(){
   const isShowBtn = this.props.navigation.getParam("showing");

   this.state = { 
      value: isShowBtn
   }
}
```